# Base64 png to Canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggeling with drawing a image on a Canvas.
What I have done so far is that I have inserted imagedata from a Canvas into a database.
The problem is that when I try to create an image of the data and draw it back on the Canvas later it does not draw the same, only some pixels may be drawen while the rest is just blank like nothing should be drawen there.

I'm getting the image data like this:

```
var CanvasData = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
CanvasData = CanvasData.toDataURL("image/png");
```

And drawing the image back on the Canvas like this (the data is stored in a database):

```
var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
var CanvasDraw = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
var ctxChange = CanvasDraw.getContext('2d');        

imagedata = new Image();
imagedata.src = result;
imagedata.onload = function(){
    ctxChange.drawImage(imagedata, 0, 0);
}
```

Here's a link to pastebin for an example of imagedata: http://pastebin.com/XGmV49k9
Result is the data that is returned from a AJAX call and is the same as what is stored in the database.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that error in this line:

```
imagedata.src = result;
```

Should be:

```
imagedata.src = CanvasData;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, forgot to add that part of the code. Result is the actual string that is stored in the database, it is received from an AJAX-call. Hence, it's the image data.

Comment: Seems that error in base64 image. Try to paste it in browser address bar. It fails. But if you try to insert data from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme it shows image

Comment: Yeah, it worked when I used the data on the url you posted, draw a red dot in the left corner (which is right). Don't see what's wrong with toDataURL when I use it in my code then :S

Comment: Try to paste toDataURL value into browser address bar before adding it to database. Maybe this is limit of text storage in DB? For example base64 is too long and truncated by server

Comment: I think you're right. There is something wrong when I store or load out the data from the database, will take a deeper look into it.Thanks for your help :)